# How to call a method on an object in an arraylist

Tags: java, list, methods, hashmap

So I have an class called Team that is used to create Team objects. In another class called LeagueAdmin I create a map of type `map<String, List<Team>` as you can see in my code I set the key to a division string and then assign the team objects to different divisions. 
My issue is where I am trying to create a method that finds two specified teams in a division, compares two integers and if x is bigger than y call a certain method to each object. I.e if teamA scores more goals than teamB, increase object with the same name as teamA's win value by 1.

My LeageAdmin code is:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class LeagueAdmin {

private Map<String, List<Team>> teams;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class LeagueAdmin
 *
 */
public LeagueAdmin() {
    this.teams = new HashMap<>();
}
public void addTeam(String division, Team team) {
    if (!this.teams.containsKey(division)) {
        List<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<>();
        teamList.add(team);
        this.teams.put(division, teamList);
    } else {
        List<Team> newTeam = this.teams.get(division);
        newTeam.add(team);
        this.teams.put(division, newTeam);
    }
}
public void recordResult(String division, String teamA, String teamB, int teamAScore, int teamBScore)
{

    List<Team> teamList = teams.get(division);
    for(Team team : teamList) {
        if(teamA.equals(team.getName())) {
            teamA = String.valueOf(team);
        } else if (teamB.equals(team.getName())) {
            teamB = String.valueOf(team);
        }
    }
    if (teamAScore == teamBScore)
    {
        teams.get(division).get(teamA).incDrew();
        teams.get(division).get(teamB).incDrew();
    } else if (teamAScore > teamBScore) {
        teams.get(division).get(teamA).incWon();
        teams.get(division).get(teamB).incLost();
    } else {
        teams.get(division).get(teamA).incLost();
        teams.get(division).get(teamB).incWon();
    }
}
```

}

and code for Team is:

```
    public class Team
    {
        private String name;
        private String division;
        private int won;
        private int drew;
        private int lost;
        // no need to record points as = 3*won + drew


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Team
 */
public Team(String aName, String aDivision)
{
    name = aName;
    division = aDivision;
    // no need to set won, drew and lost to 0
}


/**
 * getter for attribute points
 */
public int getPoints()
{
    return 3 * won + drew;
}

/**
 * getter for name
 */
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

/**
 * getter for division
 */
public String getDivision()
{
    return division;
}
/**
 * getter for won
 */
public int getWon()
{
    return won;
}

/**
 * getter for drew
 */
public int getDrew()
{
    return drew;
}

/**
 * getter for lost
 */
public int getLost()
{
    return lost;
}

/**
 * increments the number of games won
 */
public void incWon()
{
    won = won + 1;
}

/**
 * increments the number of games drawn
 */
public void incDrew()
{
    drew = drew + 1;
}

/**
 * increments the number of games lost
 */
public void incLost()
{
    lost = lost + 1;
}

/**
 * setter for division
 */
public void setDivision(String aDivision)
{
    division = aDivision;
}

public String toString()
{
    return ("Team " + name + ", division: " + division + " stats: Won: " + won
            + ", drew: " + drew + ", lost: " + lost + ", points: " + getPoints());
}
```

}

As you can see the code for the method recordResult() is the one I am having issue with, where I am referencing the string from the arguments of the method it seems to think it should be receiving an integer? Is my code even nearly right or is there a better way?

```
public void recordResult(String division, String teamA, String teamB, int teamAScore, int teamBScore)
{
    teamA = null;
    teamB = null;

    List<Team> teamList = teams.get(division);
    for(Team team : teamList) {
        if(teamA.equals(team.getName())) {
            teamA = String.valueOf(team);
        } else if (teamB.equals(team.getName())) {
            teamB = String.valueOf(team);
        }
    }
    if (teamAScore == teamBScore)
    {
        teams.get(division).get(teamA).incDrew();
        teams.get(division).get(teamB).incDrew();
    } else if (teamAScore > teamBScore) {
        teams.get(division).get(teamA).incWon();
        teams.get(division).get(teamB).incLost();
    } else {
        teams.get(division).get(teamA).incLost();
        teams.get(division).get(teamB).incWon();
    }
}
```

Comment: You set `teamA` to null. Why? Not only will this throw a NPE on the line `if(teamA.equals(team.getName()))`, it throws away the value of `teamA`

Comment: I have removed it, I must have left it in from a different solution I was trying, still get the same error without that there though.

Comment: Whats the exact error you are getting?

Comment: `method get in interface java.util.List<E> cannot be applied to given types;
required: int; found: java.lang.String;`

Comment: `teams.get(division)` returns a `List`, and you then call `.get(teamA)`, is passing a `String` to `get()`, which accepts an int argument. Look into `indexOf`

Comment: I feel maybe I am trying to reach my destination the wrong way. Regardless of what value is assign `indexOf()` it throws index out of bound exception errors unless I am implementing it wrong. I tried:
`teams.get(division).get(teamA.indexOf(0)).incDrew();`

Comment: You are calling `teamA.indexOf`, when you want to be calling `indexOf` on the `List`

Comment: Try `teams.get(division).stream().filter(team -> team.getName().equals(teamA)).findFirst().orElse(new Team()).incDrew();`. You may want a different value in `orElse()`

Answer (score 0):

You are close to something usable! `recordResults()` looks like it's intended to modify the state of your `Team` objects, but since the method accepts the team name instead of a `Team` object, you'll need to do a lookup first.

Your `for` loop is looking through the `Team` objects in the appropriate division for a `Team` with the name provided in the function arguments `teamA` or `teamB`. This is good, you just need to store the `Team` object in your variable instead of the team name, so you can access it later on in the method. So instead of storing `String.valueOf(team)`, you'll want to store `team`.

Hold up a minute, you say. I can't put a `Team` object into a `String` variable! And you're exactly right. Your `teamA` and `teamB` variables at the beginning of the method should be declared as type `Team` and given names that do not conflict with the method's parameter names. Personally, I would rename the method parameters `teamAName` and `teamBName` since they hold only the team name, and not the whole `Team` object.

Now that you've successfully looked up the `Team` objects by their names (we'll leave error handling as an exercise for later), you just need to call their appropriate scoring methods. So in your `if-else` blocks checking the team scores, you should call your `inc...` methods directly on the `teamA` and `teamB` variables that we saved from our lookup.